# Excel formatting for date is not working when exporting as XML

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, export-to-xml

I have created an Excel that includes a mapping file.  What I am trying to do is have users enter the data in here and press ctrl + E (I created a macro) and it would export it out as XML.  Here's the issue:  When line 1 gets exported, it keeps its date and time format in XML (Example:  In XML, time will show up as 12/01/2013).  But anything entered under that line will not show up in the format I want.  Instead, it will show up as 1345464 for date.

[image]

This thing has been very annoying because I cannot figure out what I can do to format the whole Excel document/column so it will show the date and time as text instead of weird number.

[image]

Someone please help me out.

Comment: Why is the cell alignment for dates different between your two lines of data?  Do you have different formats applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I feel stupid! It was easier than I could have ever thought:

Step1:  Drag the date that is in start date to the row you will populate data.   (Do the same for Enddate column).

[image]

Step2:  Notice a small square box at the bottom (it appears after following the step1).  Expand the square box.

[image]

Step3:  Choose the option that says:  Fill Formatting Only.

[image]

Congrats! Now try to enter/paste a date.  It should stay in left (text format).

Answer (score 2):

In VBA, use the `Format` function

`date = Format(date, "mm/dd/yyyy")`

Then change the format of the cell you store it in:

`Cells(row, col).NumberFormat = "@"`

(substitute your cell's coordinates for `row` and `col`)

Comment: but that would still export out as five digit number though right?  I want my date to export out as it is (TEXT).  I could use another column and do something like: =TEXT(P2,"MM/DD/YYYY").  But then I would be exporting an extra column.   I am not familiar with VBA, but is there a way to do this through VBA so the users do not have to do any extra work?   Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and eventually this code worked for me

```
Dim eCell as Range

 For Each eCell In Range("O20:P20")
        If Len(eCell.Value) > 0 Then
          eCell.NumberFormat = "@"
          eCell.Value = CDate(eCell.Value)

        End If
    Next
```

The CDate function converts the serial date back to normal date